# Cast func parameter type to object type

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

I have the following func:

```
var instance = new MyInstance();
var method = instance.GetType().GetMethod("MyMethod");
Func<bool, PropertyInfo, string, MyClass, object> myFunc = CreateFunc(instance, method);

private static Func<bool, PropertyInfo, string, MyClass, object> CreateFunc(
    object instance,
    MethodInfo method)
{
    var propertyHandlerInterface = instance.GetType().GetInterface(typeof(IPropertyHandler<>).Name);
    var valueType = propertyHandlerInterface.GetGenericArguments().First();
    var funcType = typeof(Func<,,,,>);
    var type = funcType.MakeGenericType(
        valueType,
        typeof(PropertyInfo),
        typeof(string),
        typeof(MyClass),
        typeof(object));
    return (Func<bool, PropertyInfo, string, MyClass, object>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(
        type,
        instance,
        method);
}
```

I can call it like this:

```
var myValue = true;
var result = myFunc(myValue, somePropertyInfo, "some string", someMyClassInstance);
```

I need to be able to cast the first parameter `bool` to `object` so that the func looks like this...

```
Func<object, PropertyInfo, string, MyClass, object> myFunc = CreateMyFunc();
```

...so I can call it like this:

```
object myValue = true; // <-- This is key, myValue is of type object.
var result = myFunc(myValue, somePropertyInfo, "some string", someMyClassInstance);
```

How would I achieve this?

To clarify: I want my `CreateFunc` to have the following signature:

```
private static Func<object, PropertyInfo, string, MyClass, object> CreateFunc(
    object instance,
    MethodInfo method)
```

instead of

```
private static Func<bool, PropertyInfo, string, MyClass, object> CreateFunc(
    object instance,
    MethodInfo method)
```

But I don't know how to cast my delegate to that type.

Comment: Can you explain what you are doing? What is `CreateFunc` supposed to do? Is it supposed to give you `Func<bool, PropertyInfo, string, MyClass, object>` or `Func<object, PropertyInfo, string, MyClass, object>`?

Comment: CreateFunc is supposed to give me ```Func<object, PropertyInfo, string, MyClass, object>```, I will update my question.

Comment: And the problem is that `MyMethod` accepts a `bool`?

Comment: yes, exactly! It implements a generic interface where T is the argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given, for example, a `Func<bool, object>` instance where you instead want a `Func<object, object>` instance, the simplest thing is to just wrap it in a lambda and cast the argument passed to it:

```cs
Func<bool, object> func1 = ...;
Func<object, object> func2 = o => func1((bool)o);
```

Keeping in mind, of course, that by doing so you have removed the type-safety the C# compiler would normally provide when using the delegate. A caller could invoke `func2` passing a parameter that is *not* a `bool` value, and an `InvalidCastException` would be thrown in that case.

If you can't guarantee that the caller using the delegate you've created in this way will always pass a `bool` value as the `object` parameter, then you'll need to include some fall-back mechanism in the wrapped delegate, e.g. check the type of the `o` parameter value and if it's not a `bool`, then pass a default value to the `func1` delegate, or simply return some default return value instead of calling the `func1` delegate.

For example:

```cs
Func<object, object> func2 = o => o is bool f ? func1(f) : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion (how to change the type of an "object"). I hope this is the "hint" you are looking for.

```
System.Convert.ChangeType(sourceObject, typeof(TargetType));
```